# Serialize an String array and store it in Session

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube

How to Store a String array which needs to be serialized and must be stored  in Session in java?
I have a String Array in Session which is not serialized I am taking a particular value from array and I am updating it.this code works fine but When i run **Sonar Qube** for my project it suggests the value which i am storing in session should be **serialized**.can u plz suggest me how can i resolve this issue?

****Make "String[]" serializable or don't store it in the session.
****`String[] array=(String[])request.getSession().getAttribute("sortvalues")
array[1]="";
                request.getSession().setAttribute("sortvalues",array);`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is describe here: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1810

Check your sonar version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java `ArrayList` class in place of `String[]` Array

`ArrayList` implements the empty `Serializable` interface .

Comment: String[] also implements Serializable (refs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html)